# When creating new branch, How to extend branch name from the existing branch (include example)

Tags: git, git-branch

for example, I have an existing branch that name is `issue_12345`

then I want to create another branch with naming `issue_12345_features`,

Is there an easy way to create a new branch referencing from the current branch name? (for example, Now I am in issue_12345 and want to create a branch starting from this current branch, the name start from the current branch name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following commands work in **Bash** and **PowerShell**.

### Git 2.22 and above:

To just create a branch:

```
git branch "$(git branch --show-current)_features"
```

To create a branch and checkout to the new branch in a single command:

```
git checkout -b "$(git branch --show-current)_features"
```

### Git version older than 2.2:

Replace `git branch --show-current` with `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`:

```
git branch "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)_features"
```

or

```
git checkout -b "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)_features"
```

Comment: ```--show-current``` will work assuming you have Git 2.22 and above

Answer (score 1):

There's not a way built into git to do this as far as I know, but if you're using Bash or something similar, you can use interpolation and `git branch --show-current`:

```sh
git checkout -b $(git branch --show-current)_features
```